# Excel operation to recognize and automatically fill in repeat pairings?

Tags: excel

Basically, I have some data that looks like this:

```
1 | a
2 | b
3 | c
4 | d
2 | b
5 |
6 |
1 |
```

etc

and I am trying to get excel to recognize that there are repeat values on the lefthand column, and fill in the righthand column with the same value I put in the first time that value in the lefthand column was seen. So for the second 1, it would auto fill in "a", but it would leave 5 and 6 blank. Entering in the values for the number column and making a series of rules isn't an option as my actual dataset has ISBN numbers on the left, and entering every single one to identify repeats is impractical. (About 900 unique isbns and probably 400 repeats). I can clarify if needed.

Comment: Easy enough using VBA by writing code for the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.  `VLOOKUP()` is probably the closest you can come with worksheet formulas but isn't really what you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, we may solve this by using a **VLOOKUP**.

If your data is on Col:A starting from A1, then write below formula to B1 and repeat all the way down:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,A:B,2,0)
```

You will get a **Circular Reference error** which you may ignore for now. All of your Col:B cells will fill with value 0 now. Try entering a hard coded value to B1 and you will see the same value next to a repeating A1 value down somewhere. When everything is over, copy Col:B and paste onto itself as **Values Only**.

Comment: I didn't end up using that exact formula, but thanks for telling me about VLOOKUP-- my solution ended up using that. Cheers!